# Pandas module not found, although

Tags: python, pandas, pip

For some reason I cannot get Pandas to work. A few year back I used Atom as IDE, back then everything was working fine. Now I wanted to refresh my Python skills by using PyCharm, however my first script results in:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

According to cmd pandas is installed:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.0 in c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.23.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2022.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas) (1.16.0)
```

Uninstalling and re-installing does not make a difference. I have tried this a couple of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you're using a different (virtual) environment at the command line and in PyCharm.  See [JetBrains docs on configuring the Python interpreter for PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html).

If Python's configured the way you expect, check the installed packages as well by following [these docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html)